# Unable to connect to SQL Server Database (ASP.NET C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string

When I attempt to establish a connection in ASP.NET (C#) to a SQL server database I get the following error:

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

**Web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Data Source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FIRE;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=firedba;Password=firedba;"/>
```

**C# Code**

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString;

if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
{
        connString = rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"];

        if (connString != null)
            myConnection.Open();
}
```

I am running the database in SQL Server (locally). The test application is in Visual Studio 2008.

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `ConnectionString` in your `SqlConnection` Object.

Use :

```
if (connString != null){
        myConnection.ConnectionString=connString;
        myConnection.Open();
}
```

Or just create the `SqlConnection` object after get the Connection String:

```
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
            myConnection.Open();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should inform the SqlConnection object which is the connection string to use when you try to open the link to the database

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString;
if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
{
    connString = rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"];

    if (connString != null)
    {
        // Create the connection, open, use and destroy releasing the resources used
        using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
             myConnection.Open();

             .... other database code here
        } 

   }
}
```